# Error in R pnorm - "Non-numeric argument to mathematical function"

Tags: r, p-value

I have a large csv file containing more than 80000 records of a contingency table and below is the first record:

```
test = data.frame(a=1, b=0, c=1, d=2014, R1=1, R2=2015, C1=2, C2=2014,
                 n=2016, sampleMean=2015, popMean=2, sdErr=2015, tScore=0.999049881)
```

Given that

`z = p_cap - p / sqrt(p*(1-p)/n)` i.e. `the observed mean minus the population mean over the standard error`.

`test.stat = test$a/test$n - test$popMean / sqrt(test$sdErr)` which evaluates to `-0.04405856`. Using the `pnorm` function to calculate the `pValue`:

`pValue = pnorm(test.stat, mean=test$sampleMean, sd=test$sdErr, lower.tail=TRUE)`. But I get the following error:

`Non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

When running the command on the following arguments, there is no error:

```
pValue = pnorm(test.stat, mean=0, sd=1, lower.tail=TRUE)
pValue
[1] 0.4824289
```

What does that error mean and how to avoid it?

In order not to post another question with same data, I have a doubt regarding the standard error. Is it the same as standard deviation? In my reference book, standard error is calculated as `test$a * sqrt(test$n)`

Thanks for your kind help in advance!

Comment: @ilanman  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: It's better to ask two questions, if you have two questions.

Comment: @JeremyMiles I thought it would be redundant to repeat the same data. Since the second question is strongly related to the context of the first question, I thought that it is OK to do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You've written:

```
sd=test$sdError
```

You should have put:

```
sd=test$sdErr
```

Comment: If you fix the question, the answer makes no sense.

Comment: Why? Could you please clarify more.

Comment: You ask a question about what's wrong with your code. I answered it. Then you edit the question so that there is nothing wrong with the code. The question isn't a question any more.